# VBA cell value (number) plays crazy

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of sensoric measurements in my excel table and some one are unreal, so i want to delete them. For that i wrote a code and it works good, but the "Motorlast" makes some Problems. Every measurement format is a "text"-format.
my problem is that a number which should be less 100 is greater 100.
See code...

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click()
' ist der TestButton

spalte = 16
anzahlZeilen = ActiveSheet.Range("A40000").End(xlUp).Row
vergleichswert = 100

If ActiveSheet.Cells(4, spalte) > vergleichswert Then
    MsgBox "Zahl " & ActiveSheet.Cells(4, spalte) & " > Vergleichswert " & vergleichswert
Else
    MsgBox "is kleiner"
End If 
End Sub
```

It should not be possible that i come into the if condition, but i do and i don't know why :D Do you have any suggestion?

[Image 1 from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Taejq.png)

[Image 2 from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiewg.png)

Comment: Consider using `isnumeric()` and/or `Val()` or `cdbl()` to turn strings into numbers.

Comment: i.e. maybe replace this line `If ActiveSheet.Cells(4, spalte) > vergleichswert` with `If cdbl(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, spalte)) > vergleichswert`. If you are dealing purely with whole numbers (no floats/decimals), `clng()` may also be an option for you.

Comment: Thank you, `Val()` works fine, `cdbl()` doesn't work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code sample, it looks like this might be running on a computer using the German language. This could affect how numbers are interpreted. In US English, a period would indicate the **decimal separator**, but in German a period could be used for **digit grouping**. Depending on the locale settings of the computer, this could impact how the expression is being evaluated.

For example, in the English locale, `"41,18">100=True` but `"41.18">100=False`

If this is what is happening, you could use the replace function to swap the period for a comma. This might solve your problem.

```
If Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, spalte),".",",") > vergleichswert Then
```

Comment: Thank you, thats a great idea, i will use this too, to swap my whole code.
The `Val()` function also works for me :)